# TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I have defined types as below

```
interface LoginFormValues {
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
}
```

but eslint gives an error like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `email` cannot be `undefined`, which seems reasonable. It is also likely `password` can't be `undefined` either. Your type definition should probably be:

```
interface LoginFormValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```